# Multiple virtual inheritance with common base class

Tags: c++, interface, virtual

I've going through some code recently to learn more about programming in C++ and I'm facing something somehow a bit odd.

I got a class declaration :

```
class myClass : public QObject, public virtual myObject::myOtherObject::myInterface {
    Q_OBJECT
    public: [...]
}
```

And I got the following error while compiling :

```
error: expected class-name before '{' token
error: myInterface is not a member of 'myObject::myOtherObject'
```

Is this a syntax error somewhere ? I can't figure out what is the problem ...

Do you happen to know what could be the solution ?

Many thanks :)

EDIT : The interface was irrelevant and the solution elsewhere. Nevertheless the answers helped .

Comment: How would we know? You haven't shown us the declaration of myObject, myOtherObject, myInterface.

Comment: Missing `#include` containing `myOtherObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a syntax error somewhere?

No, your code is syntactically correct. The following compiles fine, without error:

```
#include <QObject>

namespace myObject {
  namespace myOtherObject {
    class myInterface {
    };
  }
}

class myClass : public QObject, public virtual myObject::myOtherObject::myInterface {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
};
```

So, you need to check where your `myInterface` class is defined and make sure that it is properly included.

Comment: Hm yeah, I'll work on that. I'll come back when I have some results

Comment: All right, I found that ... the Interface used here was irrelevant. Never mind and sorry for trouble, your answer was great by the way.